# Cakephp check if today's date fits between two date intervals

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two dates in the database which are from and to dates and I would like to check if today's date fits with this date range.

Is there a way we could use Cake helper to check if today's date is within these two intervals?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you want to filter your query (which has nothing to do with helpers) or do you want to make this check in the view with some model data?

Comment: I want to return a boolean value of true if current date is between two dates

Answer (score 0):

You can filter in mysql query; or if you want to make a boolean value, you'll need to do it after query. It is as simple as comparing strings: `$inrange = '2011-01-02 12:21:00'<$mysqldate && '2011-03-02 12:21:00'>$mysqldate;`

Or if the dates are in difference format, convert to timestamp (using strtotime) and compare.